# Why aren't my soil-planted Fireblossoms growing?

Tags: terraria

I have a soil plant farm close to the surface growing all types of plants (except for Deathweed, because I don't want to deal with corruption). All the plants are maturing and blooming fine except for Fireblossoms - all Fireblossoms I've planted so far have failed to grow past the sprout stage. What could cause them to fail to grow?

Note that I'm not talking about blooming, which I know requires lava in the case of Fireblossoms, but the plant maturing to the point where it is able to bloom.

Comment: Don't fireblossoms need to be planted in Ash to grow?

Comment: @Fluttershy you cannot plant something in the wrong type of soil.

Answer (score 2):

[Fireblossom must be planted in either ash or a clay pot](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fireblossom).  You say "a soil plant farm", but I don't know if you used dirt or ash for the Fireblossoms.  It won't grow in dirt (Fluttershy's comment is correct).

Also, it may be that Fireblossom only grows on Ash in the underworld.  The wiki article on [Fireblossom Seeds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fireblossom_Seeds) suggests only potted Fireblossom will grow anywhere.

Comment: You cannot plant something in the wrong type of soil.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for that statement? All of the information I see indicates that they only grow in ash.

Comment: @JonahBishop - I linked the Terraria wiki.

Comment: @kotekzot - you need to post a screen shot of your farm.  It's impossible to say more without it.

Comment: @peacedog I don't think the source request was aimed at you.

Comment: @Fluttershy hah, it's hard to tell sometimes.

Comment: @JonahBishop they only grow in ash because they can only be planted in ash.